# FIbonacci series- Code is not printing the first term

Tags: c++, for-loop

I m trying to print a Fibonacci series using nested for loops in such a way that the outer loop drives the inner loop to do 2^i iterations. Its working but whenever I run the code it gives me the o/p **2^i-1**. which means everytime it is missing the very first term of Fibonacci series that is '0'. This is the code I wrote

```
# include <iostream>
# include <math.h>
# include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
using std::cout; // to display Output in column
using std::setw; // to display Output in column

main()
{
     int x=0, y=1, c, l, next=0, ratio, ratio_n =0 , diff =0; // Usage of double to get a better precision. 


      cout << "Enter the number of terms of Fibonacci series you want" << endl;


cout << "Number" << setw(10) << "Next" << setw(12) << "Ratio"  << setw(15) << "New ratio" << setw(20) << "Difference" << endl; // Setting the headers for the columns

for ( int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++ )
 {
    for(int c=0 ; c < (1<<i) ; c++)    
    {
         ratio = ratio_n; 
         next = x + y;
         x = y;
         y = next;
         ratio_n = y/x;
         diff = ratio_n - ratio;   

 cout << x << setw(13) << next << setw(13) << ratio << setw(13) << ratio_n << setw(20) << diff << endl; 
    }



}
 system("PAUSE");
}
```

I would appreciate some suggestions.
Thanks

Comment: Where are you starting? You seem to be printing a lot more than just the number. What are the value of x and y initially?

Comment: @Sinstein x=0 and y=1

Answer (score 1):

You must start by printing the first 2 Fibonacci values, `0` and `1` and then modify them progressively to get the entire series. You start by setting the values of `x` and `y` but you do not print them, the first value you print is the value of `next` which has been set to `x + y`.

Comment: its still iterating 2^i-1 times. I just updated the question and added the complete code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Move your `cout` to first line in the inner `for` loop and print `x` instead of `next`. So your inner `for` loop would contain:

```
cout << c << setw(13) << x << setw(13) <<endl; 
next = x + y;
x=y;
y=next;
```

Comment: even after changing the code, its still iterating 2^i-1 times. I just updated the question and added the complete code. can you please have a look

Comment: Inner for loop iterates correctly for 2^i times. Confirm exactly what is your problem!

Comment: When I run the code the number of terms that are printed are not 2^i but 2^i-1. For example if for outer loop i=4 then inner loop iterates 2^4 times but  the program is printing 15 terms not 16. Hope this makes the question more clear. Thanks

Comment: First of all, 15 terms is the total count of ALL the terms printed after ALL the for loops are done iterating. Second, your condition is i < 4 (and not i <= 4) so inner loop would never iterate through 2^4 times. It only iterates 2^3 time.

Comment: You are totally right, it wouldn't. So how can I make it iterate for exactly 16 times?

Comment: Your inner loop iterates 1, 2, 4 and 8 times (total = 15 times) for i = 0, 1, 2 and 3. If you want 16 iterations, why not write just 1 for loop iterating 16 times?